Integral involving the zeta function along the critical line
WolframAlpha claims that
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|(3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\ln(2)t))}{t^2 +\frac{1}{4}}dt=\pi\ln(2)$$
and I don't know how to show this. I tried removing the zeta term to get a feeling for it.
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{3-\sqrt{8}\cos(\ln(2)t)}{t^2 +\frac{1}{4}}dt=\left[6\arctan(2t)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\Re\left(2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{t=\frac{i}{2}}\frac{e^{i\ln(2)t}}{t^2 +\frac{1}{4}}\right)=6\pi-4\pi=2\pi$$
It becomes easier, but doesn't give much insight for the original problem. I saw that, if $\omega=\frac{1}{2}+it$, then it becomes
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\zeta(\omega)\zeta({\omega}^{*})}(-1+2^{\omega})(-1+2^{{\omega}^{*}})}{\omega {\omega}^{*}}dt$$
but I don't particularly see how it helps.

Could you please provide a link to the WolframAlpha evaluation?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=example+definite+integrals+of+zeta%28t%29

Perhaps the result is related to the other integral
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\left(1-2^{1-(\sigma+i t)}\right) \zeta(i t+\sigma)}{\sigma+i t}\right| , dt=\frac{\pi \left(1-2^{1-2 \sigma}\right) \zeta(2 \sigma)}{\sigma}\tag{1}$$
evaluated at $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}$ since
$$\frac{1}{2}, \underset{\sigma\to\frac{1}{2}}{\text{lim}}\frac{\pi \left(1-2^{1-2 \sigma}\right) \zeta(2 \sigma)}{\sigma}=\pi \log (2)\tag{2}.$$

That would make sense. Where defined, they look to be holomorphic functions that are real on the real axis, so I guess they satisfy $f^{}(z)=f(z^{})$, which brings the equality when we take the limit. Of course, that leaves us to then wonder about evaluation of that more general integral.
